# Problemas al insertar galeria en tema propio de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

He creado un tema de wordpress desde 0, todo funciona perfectamente, pero me tope con un detalle...

Estoy utilizando la version 5.5.1 (la mas reciente al dia de hoy), el problema lo tengo cuando creo un post y quiero insertar un bloque tipo "galeria", inserto 4 imagenes, y le digo que quiero 2 columnas, el editor me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es una cuadricula de 2x2, pero el post me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dato adicional, si selecciono el tema "Twenty Nineteen", si me las muestra correctamente, por lo que entiendo que algo me debe de faltar implementar en mi tema.

De antemano agradezco cualquier gesto de ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno me autorespondo para quien le haya sucedido.

De acuerdo a la ayuda brindada por Baruch Spinoza, lo primero que hice fue agregar el soporte al tema en el archivo functions.php de la siguiente manera:

```
function gutenberg_setup () {
    
    add_theme_support('wp-block-styles');
    add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
    }
    add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'gutenberg_setup');
```

Posteriormente, agregue el

```
wp_head()
```

a mi archivo header.php en la linea 1.

Con esto pude resolver el problema.

Espero les pueda servir a los futuros developers que se topen con este problema.

Comment: ¡Excelente! Marca tu respuesta como la aceptada para orientar a los futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que no estés registrando el CSS del editor de bloques de WordPress

Puedes dar soporte a estos estilos fácilmente agregando las siguientes líneas a tu archivo functions.php

```php
add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );
add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
```

Comment: Hola Baruch, mcuhas gracias por tu respuesta, pero haciendo lo que comentas, solo logro cambiar el estilo del editor, sin embargo el post se sigue mostrando igual, podrias echarme otra mano por favor?

Comment: Si, una disculpa, parece que ese código es más bien para el backend. Veré si puedo crear un ejemplo para el CSS del frontend.

Comment: muchas gracias, espero puedas apoyarme.

Comment: He editado la respuesta, quedo atento a tus comentarios.

Comment: hola baruch, disculpa la demora, fijate que agregue las 2 lineas al archivo functions, pero el problema persiste. Espero me puedas apoyar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, te comento ya pude hacerlo, envio la solucion dentro del post. Muchas gracias ya que sin tu ayuda no hubiese podido.